# Is there a Socrata API for reading a dataset's metadata?

Tags: socrata

Apart from the column names and types in the HTTP header, is there any way to access a dataset's metadata via the Socrata REST API?

The following fields in the "About" window are of high interest:

- category
- tags
- row count
- visits
- downloads

In addition, there are:

- community rating
- raters
- comments
- contributors
- data provided by
- source link

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried

```
https://yoursocratadomain.com/api/views/xxxx-xxxx/rows.json
```

to see if everything you are looking for is there?

Comment: Thanks much - that's most of it!  I had long given up on getting any help.  Is "api/views" documented somewhere?  I don't see it in the docs, I'm wondering if there's more that I don't know about.  I've been using "resources".  While you're here... could you look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29783413/is-there-a-socrata-api-for-reading-a-sites-catalog)?

Comment: I didn't see it documented anywhere ... If you open any socrata dataset .. you will see an export button on the top right ..  Click on that .. Download panel  will be expanded .. hover your mouse over JSON link .. and notice the link URL ... it is the same structure I mentioned in the answer. Thats how I figured it out.  :-)