# Is there a Socrata API for reading a site's catalog?

Tags: socrata

Is there a Socrata API for reading a site's catalog of datasets?

For example, for Boston, is there an API equivalent of [this page](https://data.cityofboston.gov/)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
https://data.cityofboston.gov/data.json
```

That should have every dataset in JSON format.

Comment: Thanks again.  How'd you figure _this_ one out?

Comment: I had asked a question similar to yours at the time Socrata was doing a demo for our agency. It isn't documented on their API page.

Comment: One thing to watch out for is that the format of the `data.json` and the `/api/views/abcd-1234.json` are quite different from each other. For instance, tags are "keywords" in the data.json.

Answer (score 0):

There is also a (beta) API available for catalog reading/searching, which may be easier to filter/parse than the data.json file (but either would work!). You can find information about this here: http://labs.socrata.com/docs/search.html.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: @manetsus - Are you a bot, or do you really want HoogieMan to replicate the beta, evolving API docs here?  This is the kind of mindless regurgitation of SO rules that gives me conniptions.

Comment: @EdStaub "You can find information..." I just ask to add more 'information' here as I got it in review queue. However, now, it seems to me that your question is off-topic in stackoverflow as you are asking for an API. Thanks.